# How to add objects to an ArrayList?

Tags: oop, arraylist, jframe, jpanel

I am very new on programming, and I am trying to build a little game so I can teach myself OOP, however I have an problem that I cant solve it at all.

I have a class ComponentsPanel from which I am calling another (JavaFish) as an ArrayList. The addFish() method adds to the ArrayList a JavaFish. When I call addFish() method from the  constructor works perfectly fine.

The problem is, when I call it from the start(), from another class and package, it dose not add any element to the ArrayList.

Main class

```
    package framework;

    public class Core {

            JFrame window;
            ComponentsPanel panel;
            int width = 600;
            int height = 400;

            public void start() {
                window = new JFrame();
                window.setTitle("Java Game");
                window.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
                window.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
                window.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
                window.setResizable(false);

                panel = new ComponentsPanel();
                window.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                window.setVisible(true);
                window.pack();
            }

            public void stop() {
                window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            }

        }
```

ComponentsPanel

```
        package framework;

        public class ComponentsPanel extends JPanel {
            ArrayList<JavaFish> javaFishes = new ArrayList<JavaFish>();

            public ComponentsPanel() {
                javaFishes = new ArrayList<JavaFish>();
                //addFish(new JavaFish(100, 100, 25, 25));
            }

            public void addFish(JavaFish javaFish) {    
                javaFishes.add(javaFish);
                repaint();
            }

            public void start() {
                addFish(new JavaFish(100, 100, 25, 25));
            }

            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) { 
                for (JavaFish jFish : javaFishes) {
                    jFish.draw(g);
                }
            }
       }
```

Fish class

```
        package framework;

        public class JavaFish {

            BufferedImage img;
            private int x_pos;
            private int y_pos;
            private int sizeX;
            private int sizeY;

            public JavaFish(int x_pos, int y_pos, int sizeX, int sizeY) {
                this.x_pos = x_pos;
                this.y_pos = y_pos;
                this.sizeX = sizeX;
                this.sizeY = sizeY;
            }

            public void draw(Graphics g) {
                BufferedImage JavaFish = LoadImage("img/JavaFish.png");
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2d.drawImage(JavaFish, x_pos, y_pos, sizeX, sizeY, null);

            }

            BufferedImage LoadImage(String FileName) {
                img = null;
                try {
                    img = ImageIO.read(new File (FileName));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   
                return img;

            }

    }
```

Simulation class

```
        package user;

        import framework.ComponentsPanel;
        import framework.Core;

        public class Simulation {
            Core c;
            ComponentsPanel panel;
            boolean endSim = false;

            public Simulation() {
                c = new Core();
                panel = new ComponentsPanel();
            }

            private void populate() {
                panel.start()
            }

            private void updateWorld() {
                while (!endSim) {
                    c.start();
                    break;
                }
                c.stop();
            }

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                Simulation simulation = new Simulation();
                simulation.populate();
                simulation.updateWorld();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

start() method present in ComponentsPanel is not a lifecycle method. So unless you invoke start() method manually it won't get invoked. You can add a print statement for tracking the calls.

Comment: well, I have to say @Geetha that I tried to simplified the code in here. But actually I called start() method from another class. I have just add it the class that I am calling the method from.

Answer (score 0):

@Cristea Thank you for the updated code.

This will work if you call the addFish() method on the ComponentsPanel instance created in Core class's start() method as below.

```
public void start() {
    window = new JFrame();
    window.setTitle("Java Game");
    window.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    window.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    window.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    window.setResizable(false);

    panel = new ComponentsPanel(); // This panel is passed to the JFrame
    panel.addFish(new JavaFish(100, 100, 25, 25));  // so do addFish() here. 
    window.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.pack();
}
```

The problem with your code was, you are creating two instances of ComponentsPanel class. On the first instance(let's call it panel-1 ) you created, you are calling addFish() method, through the method below. This start() method  is called on panel-1.

```
        // panel you used to call this start() method was not used in JFrame
        public void start() {               
            addFish(new JavaFish(100, 100, 25, 25)); 
        }
```

Then you are creating 2nd instance of ComponentsPanel class(let's call it panel-2) from the Core class's start() method and panel-2 does not do addFish(). But this instance (panel-2)is what is added to the JFrame, which will be used for the purpose of paint(). Since panel-2 does not do addFish(), paint() does not find any JavaFishes.

Remember, **instance variable javaFishes is specific to each instance of ComponentsPanel**. javaFishes added by panel-1 would not be available for panel-2.